# How to multiprocess, multithread a big file by dividing into small chunks based on values of a particular column?

Tags: python, multithreading, awk, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have written a python program for a biological process https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186396/solve-the-phase-state-between-two-haplotype-blocks-using-markov-transition-proba .

If you look into that program you can see that the program takes a lots of time in computing data from two consecutive lines (or keys, vals) at a time. I am not putting the whole code here, but for simplicity I am creating a mock file and mock program (given below) which behaves similarly at simplest level. In this mock program I am calculating, say `len(vals)` column and writing it back to an output file.

Since the computation is CPU/GPU bound while doing `for (k1, v1) and (k2, v2) ....` in the original program (above link), **I want to multiprocess/thread the data analyses by** **- 1)** reading whole data in memory in a fastest possible way **2)** divide the data into chunks by unique `chr` field **3)** do the computation **4)** write it back to a file. **So, How would I do it?**

In the given mock file, computation is too simple to be GPU/CPU bound, but I just want to know how I can do it if need be.

**Note:** I had too many people asking what am I trying to achieve - I am trying to multiprocess/thread the given problem. If I put my original whole big program here, nobody is going to look at it. So, lets workout this small file and the small python program.

**Below is my code and data:**

```
my_data = '''chr\tpos\tidx\tvals
2\t23\t4\tabcd
2\t25\t7\tatg
2\t29\t8\tct
2\t35\t1\txylfz
3\t37\t2\tmnost
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtuv
3\t45\t5\tlfghef
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtu
3\t45\t5\tlfggg
4\t25\t3\tpqrp
4\t32\t6\trtu
4\t38\t5\tlfgh
4\t51\t3\tpqr
4\t57\t6\trtus
'''


def manipulate_lines(vals):
    vals_len = len(vals[3])
    return write_to_file(vals[0:3], vals_len)

def write_to_file(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'a')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['\t'.join(a), str(b), '\n']))
    to_file.close()

def main():
    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'w')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'idx', 'vals', '\n']))
    to_file.close()

    data = my_data.rstrip('\n').split('\n')


    for lines in data:
        if lines.startswith('chr'):
            continue
        else:
            lines = lines.split('\t')
        manipulate_lines(lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First you have to figure out what you expect to win from multiprocessing/threading. One thing to consider is if your program is CPU bound or IO bound; that is, does the program spend most of its time doing calculations or does it spend most of its time doing IO (reading from/writing to files/console et c.)? If it is CPU bound, you may be able to speed up the calculations by using multiple cores, if your data can be parallelized (multiprocessing). If your data is IO bound, you should ensure that you do all calculations you need _while_ waiting for data (mutlithreading or asyncio).

Comment: You are basically explaining the same thing that I have been reading all along. What I wanted is not a redundant information, but an actual code so I can visually see what multiprocessing/threading is and how it can be applied to real life data problem. So, I added a very simple program where I would want to optimize it by splitting file into multiple parts (by `chr` field), doing the calculation and writing it back as simple file.

Comment: OK, that was not clear from your description. You asked "where/how/why a multiprocessing/threading can be added on this code." To answer that, more information is needed. But now, specifying that you want to do your calculations in different processes, it is another situation.

Comment: I can't understand why is it not clear to you. While it is quite understandable that doing calculation is the main part of the program, where we need to do it line by line. Splitting it into different files by `chr` would be way to do multiprocessing/threading. Also, what more is information is needed - can you explain.?

Comment: A good answer to this question, would be a very clear and conceptual example to the problem of multiprocessing/threading for the beginners and intermediate level pythonists. Why add more information to make it complicated?

Comment: @JohanL: I just improved the details in the question. Let me know if you think it's better.

Comment: Reading and writing files is I/O bound, not CPU bound. Unless your real code is quite different from this, your bottleneck is the disk, and parallelizing the writing will only make it slower.

Comment: hi @tripleee: My real code isn't this. It is quite intensive in what is happening computationally in each line (actully to consecutive dictionaries from two lines at a time). Putting my original code is simply putting the question at misery. All, I want to see is, if there is a way I can load all the data into memory (no memory related problem on my computer side), then split the computation process by `chr`. One answer below proposed optimizing the for-loop, but I am not interested in that. I want to split the work by different `chr` fields that's all. I can later check if it worked.

Comment: Your example also doesn't show any connection between the data. If each record is processed in isolation without access to any other data, there is no need for multithreading. Sounds like in your *actual* scenario you would like to keep one set of data shared between all processes or threads, but your code example doesn't show how, and it's hard to speculate based on just your brief oral summary in comments.

Comment: What kind of connection between the data? I bascially want to run the process in parallel by different `chr` by splitting it in some way. So, I start with one file - load it into memory in a fastest way - split by chr - multiprocess/thread - do computation - write as one file. It may seem as I/O based issue, but I will check that out. For, now I just want to work out multithread/process by `chr`.

Comment: A length calculation obviously only needs the current record. Checking its similarity to another record needs the other record to be in memory, too. Checking for similarity with all records needs all records to be  available. Your exposition sounds like pairwise would be enough, but can you decide which pairs to compare (or otherwise process) already when you partition the data?

Comment: @tripleee : Only records are compared within each data set that have same `chr` values. So, I want to multiprocess/thread dataset with different `chr` values.

Answer (score 1):

An issue to handle when using multiple processes to handle data, is to preserve order. Python has come up with a rather nice way of handling this, using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, which can be used to `map` the processes over the input data. This will then take care of returning the results in order.

However, the processing may still be out of order, so to use it properly, only processing, and no IO access should be run in the subprocesses. Therefore, to use this in your case, a small rewrite of your code needs to be performed, that have all IO operations happening in the main process:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
from random import randint

my_data = '''chr\tpos\tidx\tvals
2\t23\t4\tabcd
2\t25\t7\tatg
2\t29\t8\tct
2\t35\t1\txylfz
3\t37\t2\tmnost
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtuv
3\t45\t5\tlfghef
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtu
3\t45\t5\tlfggg
4\t25\t3\tpqrp
4\t32\t6\trtu
4\t38\t5\tlfgh
4\t51\t3\tpqr
4\t57\t6\trtus
'''

def manipulate_lines(vals):
    sleep(randint(0, 2))
    vals_len = len(vals[3])
    return vals[0:3], vals_len

def write_to_file(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'a')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['\t'.join(a), str(b), '\n']))
    to_file.close()

def line_generator(data):
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('chr'):
            continue
        else:
           yield line.split('\t')

def main():
    p = Pool(5)

    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'w')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'idx', 'vals', '\n']))
    to_file.close()

    data = my_data.rstrip('\n').split('\n')

    lines = line_generator(data)
    results = p.map(manipulate_lines, lines)

    for result in results:
        write_to_file(*result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program does not split the list after its different `chr` values, but instead it processes entry by entry, directly from the list in maximally 5 (argument to `Pool`) sub-processes.

To show that the data is still in the expected order, I added a random sleep delay to the `manipulate_lines` function. This shows the concept but may not give a correct view of the speedup, since a sleeping process allows another one to run in parallel, whereas a compute-heavy process will use the CPU for all of its run time.

As can be seen, the writing to file has then to be done, once the `map` call returns, which assures that all subprocesses has been terminated and returned their results. There is quite some overhead for this communication behind the scene, so for this to be beneficial, the compute part must be substantially longer than the write phase, and it must not generate *too* much data to write to file.

In addition, I have also broken out the `for` loop in a generator. This is so that input to the `multiprocessing.Pool` is available upon request. Another way would be to pre-process the `data` list and then pass that list directly to the `Pool`. I find the generator solution to be nicer, though, and have smaller peak memory consumption.

Also, a comment on multithreading vs multiprocessing; as long as you do compute-heavy operations, you should use multiprocessing, which, at least in theory, allows the processes to run on different machines. In addition, in cPython - the most used Python implementation - threads hit upon another issue, which is the global interpreter lock (GIL).This means that only one thread can execute at a time, since the interpreter blocks access for all other threads. (There are some exceptions, e.g. when using modules written in C, like numpy. In these cases the GIL can be released while doing numpy calculations, but in general this is not the case.) Thus, threads are mainly for situations where your program is stuck waiting for slow, out-of-order, IO. (Sockets, terminal input, et c.)

Answer (score -2):

I've only used threading a few times, and I have not tested this code below, but from a quick glance, the for loop is really the only place that could benefit from threading.

I'll let other people decide though.

```
import threading

my_data = '''chr\tpos\tidx\tvals
2\t23\t4\tabcd
2\t25\t7\tatg
2\t29\t8\tct
2\t35\t1\txylfz
3\t37\t2\tmnost
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtuv
3\t45\t5\tlfghef
3\t39\t3\tpqr
3\t41\t6\trtu
3\t45\t5\tlfggg
4\t25\t3\tpqrp
4\t32\t6\trtu
4\t38\t5\tlfgh
4\t51\t3\tpqr
4\t57\t6\trtus
'''


def manipulate_lines(vals):
    vals_len = len(vals[3])
    return write_to_file(vals[0:3], vals_len)

def write_to_file(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'a')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['\t'.join(a), str(b), '\n']))
    to_file.close()

def main():
    to_file = open('write_multiprocessData.txt', 'w')
    to_file.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'idx', 'vals', '\n']))
    to_file.close()

    data = my_data.rstrip('\n').split('\n')

    for lines in data:
        if not lines.startswith('chr'):
            lines = lines.split('\t')
        threading.Thread(target = manipulate_lines, args = (lines)).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```