# How to read multiple files into multiple threads/processess to optimize data analyses?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to read 3 different files in python and do something to extract the data outof it. Then I want to merge the data into one big file.

Since each individual files are already big and take sometime doing the data processing, I am thinking if

- I can read all three files at once (in multiple threads/process)
- wait for the process for all files to finish
- when all output are ready then pipe all the data to downstream function to merge it.

Can someone suggest some improvement to this code to do what I want.

```
import pandas as pd

file01_output = ‘’
file02_output = ‘’
file03_output = ‘’

# I want to do all these three “with open(..)” at once.
with open(‘file01.txt’, ‘r’) as file01:
    for line in file01:
        something01 = do something in line
        file01_output += something01

with open(‘file02.txt’, ‘r’) as file01:
    for line in file01:
        something02 = do something in line
        file02_output += something02

with open(‘file03.txt’, ‘r’) as file01:
    for line in file01:
        something03 = do something in line
        file03_output += something03

def merge(a,b,c):
    a = file01_output
    b = file01_output
    c = file01_output

    # compile the list of dataframes you want to merge
    data_frames = [a, b, c]

    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,
                       on=['common_column'], how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('.')
```

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit happening in the functions to be opening files in vanilla python and ending with a list of dataframes. Are you sure that your bottleneck can be fixed by multiprocessing file reads?

Comment: Can you explain in a more clear words? Isn't it a bottle neck that I have finish reading 3 files. I am thinking if there a way to read all three files at once; if not load all 3 files in memory and then process in parallel. I am am trying to get an example that isnot overwhelming.

Comment: You talk about processing data. Is that `do something in line` part? If that is really CPU bound job, then multiprocessing is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, its a CPU bound job.

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is what you want

Comment: Can someone point out to a good simple example on multithreading/processing. I have read hundred of examples on stackoverlow and google, but I am not able to work it out on my problem. I do understand that my problem is not I/O, and I want computation to run in parallel. Any suggestions?

Comment: @everestial007 Are those files that you read from being updated while being read from?

Comment: I can do both: Update it while I read it or pipe them from other upstream process (like `awk, grep`, etc. ). But, I need a way to run computation (`for lines in ....` in each file) in parallel so I don't have to complete each job in serial before transferring them to panadas, but I want parallel processing. Say , in this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737403/how-to-run-multiprocessing-and-or-multithreading-in-the-given-data-and-python-pr , I want to split file using awk and multiprocess/thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to use multiprocessing in your problem so I'll just propose one way. Since, as you mentioned, the processing happening on the data in the file is CPU bound you can run that in a separate process and expect to see some improvement (how much improvement, if any, depends on the problem, algorithm, # cores, etc.). For example, the overall structure could look like just having a `pool` which you `map` a list of all the `filenames` which you need to process and in that function you do your computing.

It's easier with a concrete example. Let's pretend we have a list of CSVs `'file01.csv', 'file02.csv', 'file03.csv'` which have a `NUMBER` column and we want to compute whether that number is prime (CPU bound). Example, `file01.csv`:

```
NUMBER
1
2
3
...
```

And the other files look similar but with different numbers to avoid duplicating work. The code to compute the primes could then look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sympy import isprime

def compute(filename):
    # IO (probably not faster)
    my_data_df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # do some computing (CPU)
    my_data_df['IS_PRIME'] = my_data_df.NUMBER.map(isprime)

    return my_data_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filenames = ['file01.csv', 'file02.csv', 'file03.csv']

    # construct the pool and map to the workers
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(compute, filenames)
    print(pd.concat(results))
```

I've used the `sympy` package for a convenient `isprime` method and I'm sure the structure of my data is quite different but, hopefully, that example illustrates a structure you could use too. The plan of performing your CPU bound computations in a `pool` (or list of `Process`es) and then merge/reduce/concatenating the result is a reasonable approach to the problem.

Comment: Hi Paul, you provided a very comprehensive explanation compared to what I have been reading so far. Thank you! I am hoping I can achieve what I am doing now. I had to rewrite my problem, because I was not receive response in my other problem (which isn't duplicate though). I am trying to understand this parallelization in python for some weeks, but in regards to my data. Would you have time to put your perspective in this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737403/how-to-multiprocess-multithread-a-big-file-by-dividing-into-small-chunks-based .